# Ajax post HashWithIndifferentAccess error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `tickets.js.coffee`:

```
$.ajax '/comments/add',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html'
  success: ( data ) ->
    alert 'success'

<%= form_for @comment, :url => user_ticket_message_comments_path( @user, @ticket, m ), :html => { :class => "add-comment", :id => "add-comment-" + @ticket.id.to_s } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :body, "Add comment" %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :message_id, :value => m.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Add comment" %>
<% end %>
```

Comments table:

```
id | message_id | body
----------------------
```

CommentsController:

```
def create
  @comment = params[:comment]
  @comment.save
end
```

My routes.rb:

```
resources :messages do
  resources :comments
end
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `save' for {"body"=>"awef", "message_id"=>"15"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Comment belongs to a Message and Message has many comments.

Where should I look to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params[:comment]` is a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html), not a `Comment` object, and thus can't be "saved". You need to create a new `Comment` object and assign each attribute to it, then save the `Comment` object:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.save
end
```

Depending on how "new" your app is, `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` may be set to `true`, in which case the above will give you a security error and you should read the [Rails Guides on Mass-Assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) for more information about how to properly assign attributes (you should actually read it either way).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Can't believe I overlooked that.